# Result of (operand1 < operand2) || (~operand1 < carry)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand the logic of the code below that adds with a carry:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

inline unsigned char add_uint64_generic(uint64_t operand1, uint64_t operand2, unsigned char carry, unsigned long long *result)
{
    operand1 += operand2;
    *result = operand1 + carry;
    return (operand1 < operand2) || (~operand1 < carry);
}

int main()
{
    uint64_t operand1 = 10000;
    uint64_t operand2 = 2000;
    char carry = 255;
    unsigned long long r;
    std::cout << "operand1 < operand2: " << (operand1 < operand2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "(~operand1 < carry): " << (~operand1 < carry) << std::endl;
    cout<<(int) add_uint64_generic(operand1,operand2,carry,&r) << std::endl;
    cout<< r;
    return 0;
}
```

prints

```
operand1 < operand2: 0
(~operand1 < carry): 1
0
12255
```

If

```
operand1 < operand2: 0
(~operand1 < carry): 1
```

how can `(operand1 < operand2) || (~operand1 < carry)` be `0`? `0||1 = 1`.

Also, this looks like some carry operation. What does `~operand1` have to do with carry here?

Comment: Your `operand1` inside the function is different than the one in `main` (you're adding `operand2` to it inside the function).

Answer (score 0):

`std::cout << "(~operand1 < carry): " << (~operand1 < carry) << std::endl;`
doesn't match what the function does.  Try

`std::cout << "(~sum < carry): " << (~(operand1+operand2) < carry) << std::endl;`  and likewise for the other comparison, as `operand1` should really be the sum.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like part of a arbitrary precision addition. It takes three inputs and returns two outputs. The inputs are the two matching words of the arbitrary precision numbers (`operand1` and `operand2`) and a carry from the previous (lower word) operation. It returns the sum, *which may have overflown* and the new carry.

As the sum `operand1 + operand2 + carry` is computed, there are two opportunities for the addition to overflow, which correspond to the two halves of the operation in question (`(operand1 < operand2) || (~operand1 < carry)`).

The first addition is performed as `operand1 += operand2`, so the first check `operand1 < operand2` is equivalent to checking if the sum is smaller than one of the addends - `operand1` now stores the sum. This happens if and only if the operation overflowed (adding two non-negative numbers w/o overflow cannot make the result smaller, but performing an overflow will always make it smaller, as it effectively adds x - 2^n where x < 2^n). The second addition could have been checked the same way, but is not.

The second part of the check, `~operand1 < carry`, works proactively instead. The trick is the use of `~operand1` to compute `2**64 - operand1 - 1` (remember that `2**64` and `0` are the same number due to modular arithmetic). The expression becomes a bit easier to understand when written as `0 - operand1 - 1 < carry` which can then be simplified to `0 - operand1 <= carry`. As `2**64 - operand1` is obviously the number that needs to be added to `operand1` to achieve overflow, comparing it to `carry` should make more sense.